# Problems redirect to another html page (redirect cancels the execution of the function before it)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the code below

```
GetListTourneeByPersonnelIDFromServer();
window.location = './Calendrier.html';
```

When I execute this code there is, the redirection to the Calendar page cancels the execution of the `GetListTourneeByPersonnelIDFromServer` function,
and since I can not use the term CallBack, because in `GetListTourneeByPersonnelIDFromServer` function called it there's more to another function that contains loops,
how to resolved this problem and thanx

Comment: I'm blocked, can you help me please